# Bulk update of the same row column using trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, bulkupdate

I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE JoiningDate 
(
    Id INT,
    DateofJoining DATETIME,
    STATUS VARCHAR(10),
    DaysCount INT
)
```

This table is filled with 1000 records with DaysCount as NULL value.

I have created a trigger as below for this table to update `DaysCount`. Whenever there is an update of `DateOfJoining` or `Status` columns, `DaysCount` should get calculated in the trigger and updated automatically.

This is the outline of the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_JoiningDate] 
ON [dbo].[JoiningDate]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id INT
    DECLARE @DateJoining DATETIME
    DECLARE @Result INT

    SELECT @Id = Id,
           @DateJoining = DateofJoining, 
    FROM INSERTED   

    SET @Result = [Formula To Calculate Days]

    UPDATE JoiningDate 
    SET DaysCount = @Result  
    WHERE Id = @Id
END
```

I'm able to see the count getting updated for single record. But for bulk updates it is updating only the first record.

With the help of stackoverflow, I have tried using instead of trigger, TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(), etc options but still all other rest of the rows not getting updated.

Quicker help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to split this up into *two* separate triggers - one for `INSERT`, one for `UPDATE`. Makes it much simpler to work with the code.

Also: your trigger will be called **once** per statement - **not** once per row - so you cannot just select a value from the `Inserted` pseudo table like this (since that pseudo table will contain **all** 25 newly inserted rows - not just one):

```
SELECT 
    @Id = Id,
    @DateJoining = DateofJoining, 
FROM INSERTED
```

Which of the 25 inserted rows would you be looking at?? It's arbitrary and undetermined - plus you'll just look at *one* row and ignore all other 24 rows.....

So the `INSERT` trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_JoiningDate_Insert] 
ON [dbo].[JoiningDate]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE jd
    SET DaysCount = [Formula To Calculate Days]
    FROM JoiningDate jd
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.Id = jd.Id
END
```

Since you have no previous values, there's no need to check if one of those two columns was updated.

Your `UPDATE` trigger should look like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_JoiningDate_Update] 
ON [dbo].[JoiningDate]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE jd
    SET DaysCount = DATEDIFF(DAY, jd.DateofJoining, SYSDATETIME())
    FROM JoiningDate jd
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON i.Id = jd.Id
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON d.Id = i.Id
    -- check whether "DateOfJoining" or "Status" have been updated
    WHERE
        i.DateOfJoining <> d.DateOfJoining 
        OR i.Status <> d.Status 
END
```

Comment: Hi Marc,

My sceneario is to run the below query(ideally, it should  update all the records) and in turn all the rows of column DaysCount should get updated based on that row value.
But now, when I run the above query, it is updating the first record alone


UPDATE JoiningDate SET STATUS='Joined'

Comment: The trigger updates *only* those rows that were in fact updated. How many rows did your `UPDATE` statement affect?

Comment: for 1000 rows, for above update statement, it is saying 1000 rows(s) affected. but actually, first row alone got updated for column DaysCount other rows are still NULL

Comment: @BV: I can't reproduce your problem - in my setup, it works as intended.... there must be something else / additional be wrong in your case. Are you in fact updating either the `Status` or the `DateOfJoining` columns? Or is the `Status` *already* `Joined` for those rows that don't get updated?

Comment: Thanks Marc, Im close to the solution. I have not considered the joins while updating between inserted and deleted. i was taking the primary key from inserted table and while updating the dayscount field, im using that primary key in where clause. it. UPDATE JD SET SET DaysCount = [Formula To Calculate Days] WHERE Id=@Id. but now, I m using the above approach it is updating for all other records but first row value being updated for all other rows. what is the purpose of where clause?

Comment: @BV: the `WHERE` clause checks to see if one of either `DateOfJoining` or `Status` has changed between the *old* row (*before* the `UPDATE`), and the *new* row (*after* the `UPDATE`), since you said you wanted to update the other columns only if either one of those two columns had been changed

Comment: how can I avoid same value being updated to DaysCount for all 1000 rows for UPDATE JoiningDate SET STATUS='Joined' statement? Am I missing something here? Is it working fine for you?

Comment: @BV: the trigger will *only* update those rows that *have been updated* by your `UPDATE` statement. So if your `UPDATE` statement affects 5 rows, the trigger will update *at most* those five rows - not all 1000 rows in your table

Comment: marc_c : UPDATE JoiningDate SET STATUS='Joined'         for this update statement all rows DaysCount field is getting updated with the calculated values but same value being updated to all 1000 records.

Comment: @BV: well, without knowing what that "magic" formula really does, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you any further .... the trigger per se works.

Comment: Thing is simple. DaysCount=current date - joining date (in days). whenever there is a change in joining date dayscount filed will get updated. :)

Comment: @BV: OK, updated my response - the `INSERT` trigger really doesn't make any sense at all, since that value will be 0 for those newly inserted rows anyway, no?? But the `UPDATE` trigger make sense - and works **just fine** for me - try it for yourself!

Comment: Working fine. Thanks marc_s

Answer (score 0):

Only one record getting updated because you are updating only one records even in case of bulk records.

Also you should tell what is your exact formula look like.

You should change your code to this:

```
DECLARE @Id INT
  DECLARE @DateJoining DATETIME
  DECLARE @Result INT

    Declare @Flg int=0
    --if exists(select top 1 id from inserted)
    --set @Flg=1
    --if exists(select top 1 id from deleted)
    --set @Flg=@Flg+2
    if (COLUMNS_UPDATED(DateJoining) or COLUMNS_UPDATED([status]))
    begin

  SET @Result = [Formula To Calculate Days]
  --what is the actual formula ?
  UPDATE jd SET DaysCount = @Result  
        FROM INSERTED i
        inner join JoiningDate jd on i.id=jd.id  
end
```

Comment: This is **NOT** going to work in the case of an `INSERT`, since you set the `@Flg` to 1, but never to 2, and you execute the `UPDATE` statement **only** when `@Flg = 2` (which is not the case for an INSERT) ...... what are you trying to accomplish with that `@Flg` anyway???

Comment: Main criteria is that when certain column get updated then only update statement should fire.So flag logic is not require,neverthless i hv corrected my flag logic too.so when flag=1 that means inserted,when flag-2 that means only delete and when flag=3 that means updated.

Comment: ` UPDATE JoiningDate SET STATUS='Joined'`    But when I run the above query, as per trigger, it should update DaysCount for all the 1000 rows but it is updating the first record alone

Comment: you ARE talking about which code.basically you hv to join yourmain table with inserted table like my script above.it has to work.